# Is the category of fields small?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I know that the category of groups $\textbf{(Group)}$ and rings $\textbf{(Ring)}$ are both only [locally small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Small_and_large_categories), since any non-empty set can be made into a group or a ring.

However, when this comes to fields, I'm not sure if there's also an explicit construction making an infinite set to a field (we know not all finite set can be a field). Therefore I cannot confirm if the category of fields is small.

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

Comment: Can't an arbitrary countable set be viewed as $\mathbb{Q}?$ Or an uncountable one as $\mathbb{R}?$ Not at all sure if this helps...

Comment: Well, I doubt if what you state is correct. On the other hand, even if it is correct, can it confirm that $\textbf{(Field)}$ is not small?

Comment: Doubt no more. @伽罗瓦 is correct about the countable one. With the uncountable one, of course, one needs to be more careful.

Comment: Of course the countable one is trivial, but the uncountable is not correct, and this still doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: For $\kappa$ large enough, you can biject $2^\kappa$ with the transcendence degree $\kappa$ extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$.  So the category **(Fields)** is not small.

Comment: You are correct. I'm too stupid to come up with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's fix the rational numbers. Right? That's just one set now. Given any other set which is disjoint from $\Bbb Q$, consider the transcendental extension $\Bbb Q(A)$, as a field. This alone shows that every set can be embedded into a field. And easy cardinality check will show that $|A|=|\Bbb Q(A)|$ whenever $A$ is infinite.

In particular, via transport of structure any infinite set can be made into a field. And so far we're only talking about purely transcendental extensions of $\Bbb Q$. This can be repeated with any field instead of $\Bbb Q$ (e.g. $\Bbb F_2$) as well.

Comment: Nice! Since I didn't encounter problems of algebra, I didn't think of it right immediately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain under what conditions a category can be considered small? I thought that if it didn't contain a set of every cardinality it can be considered small.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/small+category

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Let $S$ be the class of all singleton sets (sets with just one elements). $S$ is a proper class. Why? For any set $X$, $\{X\}\in S$, so there is an injective function from the class of all sets into $S$. Now the subcategory of $\textsf{Sets}$ with objects $S$ is not small.

Comment: @伽罗瓦 Maybe you're thinking of "essentially small". For many kinds of concrete categories $C$, if $C$ doesn't contain a set of every cardinality, then $C$ is essentially small.